# For Loop - Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop that separates individuals based on their program, cip2, and their award type, ipeds. Below is a sample of what the data looks like.

```
yrqtr| cip2 | ipeds | median_wage | count
20131| 51   | 1     | 100         | 10 
20131| 51   | 3     | 100         | 10
20131| 17   | 5     | 150         | 10
20131| 4    | 7     | 150         | 10
```

I am trying to create individual dfs that would look like this:

```
yrqtr| cip2 | ipeds | median_wage | count
20131| 51   | 1     | 100         | 10
```

```
yrqtr| cip2 | ipeds | median_wage | count
20131| 51   | 3     | 100         | 10
```

I have created this for loop which separates by cip2 alone.

```
for (i in c(unique(df.emp$cip2, unique(df.emp$ipeds)))) {
    nam <- paste('df.emp', i , sep = '.')
    assign(nam, df.emp[df.emp$df2==i,])
    }
```

I have created this new for loop, but it doesn't do what I want it to.

```
for (i in unique(df.emp$df2)){    
    
    for (j in unique(df.emp$ipeds)) {
        name<- paste('df.emp', j, sep = '.')
        assign(name, df.emp[df.emp$ipeds==j,])
               }
    
        
    nam <- paste(name, i, sep = '.')
    assign(nam, df.emp[df.emp$df2==i,])
    }
```

Comment: Try `split(df.emp, list(df.emp$cip2, df.emp$ipeds))`. This creates a named list. If you want individual df's (which I do not recommend, it's better to have one object with all the df's in it) then use `list2env`.